# Three.js: forcing loop to unroll

Tags: javascript, three.js, opengl-es-2.0

When using normally three.js I get this error at Firebug:

> gl.getProgramInfoLog() (54,6): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1
>   iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll

Even all the rest looks like working properly and not giving any problem.

Trying with some examples from the net I see the same error message, you can find it for example at some examples in the net like [this one](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_convex)

When it uses three.min.js appears at line: 537 and with three.js it appears at line: 25909.

Comment: Confirmed with [r68](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r68/three.min.js) using Firefox 31. No warnings with r65.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of firefox you are using ?

there was a [bug in firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=883659) related to this. Consider upgrading.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 29, but with Firefox 28 is also happening, as well as in Chrome 34.0.1847.131m.

Comment: You can check the example I proposed, this is here: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_convex

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, checkout [three.js issue tracker](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4834). Apparently, it has been fixed.

Comment: Thx facuq, you are right, in r68 the error message has turned into a warning. This is more fair as it is not actually an error to be fixed but something in the GPU that is not being executed as expected, it means the GPU internally has created the code structure for a loop that just has one iteration. Even if the aim is to avoid such a loop, still no clear message and no clear from where exactly from the user code it's coming.