# Threejs: Rendering scene in Div - Prevent scrolling of browser window, do zoom instead (OrbitControls.js)

Tags: three.js

I have written a new tool in three.js which deals with a [cylinder in 3d](http://www.echteinfach.tv/formeln/geometrie/zylinder/) and renders the cylinder values in the scene that is located within a DIV.

JS:

```
container = document.getElementById('zylinder_3d');
var sceneWidth = document.getElementById('zylinder_3d').offsetWidth;
var sceneHeight = document.getElementById('zylinder_3d').offsetHeight;
renderer.setSize(sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="zylinder_3d"></div>
```

For the navigation I am using OrbitControls.js:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
// rotate at startup
controls.rotateLeft(-0.1);
controls.rotateUp(-0.25);
controls.dollyOut(2.5); // zoom out
```

The problem is, that if I use the mouse to **scroll** (having the mouse on top of the canvas), the entire browser window scrolls down - instead of the expected zooming.

Is there any way I can force the scroll to happen only within the scene / the canvas. In best case when the mouse is on top of the canvas.

I have tried some stop scroll advices for Javascript here on stackoverflow, but these were on "normal" DIVs not for DIVs with canvas.

Comment: Does the problem go away with `TrackBallControls`?

Comment: `var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );` solves the scrolling problem. But the mouse navigation of the trackback controls is weird, it feels unnatural and difficult, so I need to stick to OrbitControls. I have updated the question above accordingly. OR are there other Controls that behave like OrbitControls? @WestLangley offtopic: you have got 666 Answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution thanks to WestLangleys's comment above who pointed out the TrackBallControls:

Open `OrbitControls.js` and find lines:

```
function onMouseWheel( event ) {
    if ( scope.enabled === false || scope.noZoom === true ) return;
```

Add right below:

```
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
```

This is it!

It works now as expected: [Zylinder 3D Demo](https://www.matheretter.de/rechner/zylinder/)

[image: cylinder program 3d]

PS: Maybe this should be added to the original file?

Comment: I am not using the r68 since Firefox 31 throws [some errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367786/three-js-forcing-loop-to-unroll) that I don't know if they cause problems.

Comment: I have tried to update only the [OrbitControl.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) and stick with r65 but this throws the error: `TypeError: (intermediate value).setFromUnitVectors is not a function`

Comment: This is still happening in firefox albeit it's very slight. It's most noticable towards the end of a zoom in/out animation when scrolling with the mouse wheel in either direction. It however it doesn't happen in chrome. I'm using firefox 38 and the newest version of orbitControls.js.

Comment: Firefox is still scrolling the page (v41.0.1). I fixed it changing the event listener  from `DOMMouseScroll` to `MozMousePixelScroll`: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L781-L798

Comment: I guess it's not a perfect idea to manipulate code inside node_modules. What u can do instead is to instantiate OrbitControls and set ```enableZoom``` to ```false```. https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.enableZoom