# Prevent page scrolling while mouse is over scene in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, three.js

I am creating a three.js app nested inside a div on a webpage. I am using OrbitControls.js to allow zooming via the mouse-wheel. However, using the mouse-wheel causes the entire page to scroll. I need to disable scrolling when my mouse is over the canvas.

I found a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293927/threejs-rendering-scene-in-div-prevent-scrolling-of-browser-window-do-zoom-i) which was to add some code to OrbitControls.js. This solution works in Chrome and Internet Explorer, but not Firefox (those are the only browsers I tried)

Any suggestions for a solution that will work with Firefox as well?

An example of the functionality I am looking for can be seen by viewing [this link](http://www.echteinfach.tv/formeln/geometrie/zylinder/) provided in the question I referenced above (unless you are using Firefox)

JavaScript:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after some inspiration from Canvas's solution. I was convinced that it was an issue with three.js/OrbitControls.js that I didn't think to just try normal Javascript events.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var active = false; //is the mouse over the div
var scrollPosition = 0;
container.onmouseenter = function(e) {
    active = true;
    scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
};

container.onmouseleave = function(e) {
    active = false;
};

window.onscroll = function(e)
{
    if (active) {
        window.scrollTo(0,scrollPosition);
    }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems you cannot prevent the scroll event

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just listen for a scroll event on the specific div and just `scrollTop 0; scrollLeft 0;`?

Here is a jsFiddle version

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qLh22das/

HTML

```
<div id="scroller">
    <p>TEXT 1</p>
    <p>TEXT 2</p>
    <p>TEXT 3</p>
    <p>TEXT 4</p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="scroller2">
    <p>TEXT 1</p>
    <p>TEXT 2</p>
    <p>TEXT 3</p>
    <p>TEXT 4</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#scroller {
    height:100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#scroller2 {
    height:100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Javascript

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('scroller');

div1.onscroll = function(event)
{
    div1.scrollTop = 0;
    div1.scrollLeft = 0;
};
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` may be better

Comment: I did try that but it would still scroll

Comment: Ahh you are right, I didn't realize you could not prevent this event.

Comment: My div that contains the app does not have a scroll bar. I am trying to prevent the whole webpage from scrolling when the mouse is over the div. This solution only works if I manually give my div a scroll bar by setting `overflow-y: auto`, even though the scroll bar is not needed

Comment: You could try to set a variable to true and false on mouseover and mousexit like so `var dontScroll = false; div1.onmouseover = function(e) {
    dontScroll = true;
};

div1.onmouseout = function(e) {
    dontScroll = false;
};` then check in the check only stop scroll if dontScroll is true

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my current project and fixed it by changing the following lines in OrbitControls.js:

```js
# Line 781
this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox

# Line 798
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox
```

to

```js
# Line 781
this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'MozMousePixelScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox

# Line 798
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'MozMousePixelScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox
```

I already created a pull request on github: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7310