# Three JS as Angular component scrolling problem

Tags: angular, events, scroll, three.js

I'm integrating threejs scene as an Angular component into my app. I found some tutorials and many things go well. But then I added `OrbitControls` to zoom my scene and mousewheel zooming now triggers scrolling of the entire window.

I found some info but it didn't help me:

[Threejs: Rendering scene in Div - Prevent scrolling of browser window, do zoom instead (OrbitControls.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293927/threejs-rendering-scene-in-div-prevent-scrolling-of-browser-window-do-zoom-i)
http://jsfiddle.net/jmchen/ga4hwfyo/

Camera with controls init code:

```js
this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(
    75, 
    this.canvas.parentElement.offsetWidth / this.canvas.parentElement.offsetHeight, 
    0.1, 
    1000
);

this.camera.position.z    = 100;
this.scene.add(this.camera);
this.controls             = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
this.controls.minDistance = 2;
this.controls.maxDistance = 300;
this.controls.update();
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="engine-wrapper">
    <canvas #rendererCanvas id="renderCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

I tried to add some variants of this, but it changes nothing

```js
this.canvas.parentElement.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.stopPropagation()` instead of `event.preventDefault()` worked for me